# My Shower Head Screws Into A 1-1/4" Pipe!! How Do I Upgrade/Replace?

Tags: bathroom, shower

The pipe coming out of the wall that my shower head attaches to is HUGE. I measure the outside diameter at approximately 1.25"  I want to replace the "rain" style head with detachable head/wand on a long hose, but when I unscrewed this head, the pipe threads are like 1-1/4" diameter (male).  Nothing fits, and there is some kind of filter inside.  The valve is Moen. Does anyone know if I can buy other shower head assemblies for this specific pipe?  Or do I have to unscrew the pipe out of the wall and replace it with some kind of reducer and then 1/2" npt chrome pipe?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, especially if you know about this kind of product and its history and background.  I think the whole assembly is probably about 15 years old.   I just never heard of such a huge shower head pipe.

Comment: Probably a 1 inch pipe(size goes by inside).  Kind of unusual, but don't have to worry about water flow.  Imagine you are right about needing pipe reducer/s, maybe will even want a flow reducer.  Will need the metal/plastic type of pipe for the right reducer size.

Comment: "*Nothing fits*" Did you try any 1" FPT fittings? I'm guessing you didn't.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Think the OP means the new shower head does not fit, asking for parts needed to make fit.

Comment: Nothing fits means none of the shower heads or accessories that I can buy at Lowes or Home Depot fit this huge pipe.  Of course there are pipe fittings that could fit, but I was hoping not to replace this pipe, it matches the rest of the plumbing in the shower.

Answer (score 1):

[1" FNPT](https://www.engineersedge.com/hardware/taper-pipe-threads.htm) to 1/2" MNPT, in as few or as many steps as it takes to get there depending what you can find to buy. 1" nominal threaded pipe has an OD of 1.315" making that the most likely size for `approximately 1.25"` outside diameter.

Could be one fitting. 1" FNPT x 1/2" MNPT reducer, if you can find one. Looks to be an oddball, but probably someone makes one.

Could be a 1" FNPT X FNPT coupling, a 1" MNPT x 1/2" FNPT reducer, and a 1/2" MNPTxMNPT nipple. The parts in the middle, if needed, don't specifically matter so long as they fit each other.